# before I get / before getting

Tags: grammar

- I will do smth before *I get* my master's degree
- I will do smth before *getting* my master's degree

I think that both variants are right.

But what is the more idiomatic for you?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I did was check out Google Books to establish that ***paused*** is the most common word in the sequence "**he * before he**". Which led me to produce [this usage comparison chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He%20paused%20before%20he%20spoke%2CHe%20paused%20before%20speaking&year_start=1860&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image]

I'd say that's clear evidence that *both versions are fine*. They mean exactly the same thing, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the more idiomatic for you?

I think it would depend on the context of a real sentence with real actions, not just, "I will do smth"

By the way "smth" is not used by native speakers. I had to pause before I understood it.